# change URL of UIWebView in view controller from push notification appdelegate with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

```
 var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 var viewController: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view0000") as UIViewController
 self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

how to get `UIWebView` in `appdelegate.swift`

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the URL in your viewcontroller and set the value for the property in AppDelegage. Then in your ViewConroller's viewDidLoad method, set the URL property value to your UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rshankar said, assuming your viewController has the webView, I would do:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var viewController: MyViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view0000") as MyViewController
viewController.url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And this would be your MyViewController:
And whatever you want in reloadWebview

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController {
    var url = "" {
        didSet {
            reloadWebView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: viewController.url = "http://stackoverflow.com". I can't get url....it show error